# ZPL: Z64 Compression, Encoding, and CRC-16 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, printing, zpl

I am attempting to implement an algorithm for calculating LZ77 on a byte array, MIME Base64 encoding on the outputted byte array, and then a CRC-16 on the outputted byte array from the MIM Base64 encoding.  This will be done in order to compress and encode PNG images for printing to ZPL.

The CRC-16 follows the logic below:

**CRC**: A four digit CRC value in hexadecimal. If 0000 is entered, then the CRC  validation is ignored. For examples, see below.

**CRC** example 
The value of the  field is calculated the CRC-16 for the contents of a specified file using the CRC16-CCITT polynomial which is x^16 + x^12 + x^5 + 1. It is calculated using an initial CRC of 0x0000.

**checksum example** 
Given 4 bytes of data : 0x25, 0x62, 0x3F, 0x52: 
1. Adding all bytes together gives 0x118. 
2. Drop the carry nibble to get 0x18. 
3. Get the two's complement of the 0x18 to get 0xE8. 
This is the checksum byte.

I am fully aware of the previous StackOverflow discussion at the link below, but it doesn't seem to fully answer the question.

I'm alright with stitching together various items, but I don't think I can abide with porting code from JavaScript to C#.

[Printing PNG images to a zebra network printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818688/printing-png-images-to-a-zebra-network-printer)

Comment: Did you already solve your problem and what is your primary question?